# Login session is not getting nullified

Tags: asp.net

I have a login page, in this page a login session is assigned on successfully authenticating the user and this session is being used in all the pages throughout the project. In all the pages, I have put a condition

```
If(Session["login"]) == null)
    Response.Redirect("login.aspx");
```

Moreover, I'm also nullifying the session at logout.
However, this code is not working.
On clicking back button the application is getting logged in again.

Please anyone can help me in this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On page load of each page add this.

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            if (Session["login"] == null)
                Response.Redirect("Login.aspx");
            else
            {
                Response.ClearHeaders();
                Response.AddHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate");
                Response.AddHeader("Pragma", "no-cache");
            }
        }
    }
```

For more details go to the link  [disable browser's back button functionality on logout in ASP.Net](http://www.letitborn.com/blog/technical-computer-science/Disable-backbutton-functionality-on-logout-in-ASP_Net.html)

On logout button click add this

```
protected void btnLogout_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Session.Abandon();
        Session["login"] = null;
        Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ExpiresAbsolute = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-1d);
        Response.Expires = -1000;
        Response.CacheControl = "no-cache";
        Response.Redirect("Login.aspx", true);
    }
```